# Inkscape - Moving objects inside clipping group

Tags: inkscape, clipping-mask

I have an image clipped inside a rectangle shape, how can I move the image inside without affecting the rectangle shape?

Maybe it is a simple operation but I already search for hours without a right answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Select the clipped object
2. Do *Object > Clip > Release*
3. Move the image
4. Select the both the image and the clipping path
5. Do Object > Clip > Set.

Another method is to use an actual clipping group.

1. Draw a rectangle over an image
2. Select both
3. Right click and choose "Create Clip Group"
4. Double click to enter the group
5. Double click the image again to just select the image
6. Move it to the desired position.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to move the inside object without release the clip?

Comment: @GhostOrder OK I've added more instructions.

Comment: Is almost perfect, when I follow your new instructions the rectangle fill color is still showed, is it the normaI behavior? I recorded a video to try explain it better. I can fix this by removing the rectangle fill, but this is strange to me since I came from Illustrator and there when you create a clipping mask the fill of the object that clipps is automatically hidden https://youtu.be/tTeFULLKMfU

Comment: @GhostOrder Yes, remove the fill.  Inkscape isn't Illustrator!

Comment: I know I know, I just a normal reaction because one always expect all the commodities that the previous software had xD. Anyway thank you for taking the time to help me.

Comment: @GhostOrder -  it's worth noting that Inkscape has a slightly different purpose in comparison to Illustrator which was originally created for print work. Inkscape's main purpose is for creating and editing SVGs.  Inkscape is mostly built around SVG standards, not Adobe's way of doing things.

Comment: Oh thats interesting. Is impressive the amount of things you can do in a SVG format. I just knew that SVG was just a format to save vector graphics and you can use it in a website for example, but as I noted Inkscape use it as it main save format too

Answer (score 1):

#### OPTION 1:

Go to

*Edit → Preferences → Behavior → Clippaths and masks*

and select

*Put all clipped/masked objects into one group*.

This option is a "shortcut" to the manual option below (option 2).
When you clip an image again, you can double-click on clip and drag the image. Or go to OBJECTS panel and select the image within clip and drag (as shown in print below).

#### OPTION 2:

Another option is to group the image before clip.
After that, go to the *Object* menu and click *Objects…*. The selected clip object (in image below `g1566`) has an arrow. When click in the arrow, the clipped image will appears. Click in the image object (in image below `image1559`) and move/transform the image.

[image]